# Dynamics AX 2009 Business Connector connection with .NET Framework 4.x

Tags: .net, axapta, aif

I am trying to connect Dynamics AX to my WEB API in ASP.NET Framework 4.0 but it does not work with the versions greater than 3.5 so is there any workaround for this? I am actually confused because Framework 4.0 doesn't allow me to integrate Dynamics AX either its BusinessConnector.dll or Dynamics AX Web services.

Comment: Applications running on frameworks from .NET 4.0 and above will not be able to import the BusinessConnector.dll since it is running on .Net 3.5. You'll need to have some sort of a wrapper in order for your web api to work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [side by side](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/side-by-side-execution). The [compatibility test](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/axinthefield/compatibility-testing-for-microsoft-dynamics-ax/) says:

> AX 4.0 SP2 and AX 2009 RTM and SP1: Both 32 and 64 bits mode. Only supported side by side with .NET 3.5  and Visual Studio 2008.

So maybe it works if you do not uninstall .Net 3.5.